# Unix Timestamp to ISO-8601 String

Tags: oracle, timestamp, iso8601

I have an Oracle table called `ACQDATA` with a field `READDATETIME` where I store a Unix timestamp in milliseconds as an `INTEGER` (`NUMBER(38)`) type.

```
SQL> select READDATETIME from ACQDATA where ID=1000;

READDATETIME
____________
   1.4793E+12
```

I need to select that value as a ISO-8601 string (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmm`):

```
SQL> select READDATETIME from ACQDATA where ID=1000;

READDATETIME
-------------------
   1.4793E+12
```

I´ve tried to convert it using `TO_CHAR`, but the result is messy:

```
   SQL> select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(READDATETIME, 'SECOND'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from ACQDATA where ID=1000;

Error at line 1:
ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: A year is roughly 3 * 10^7 seconds.  If `readDateTime` is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, that implies that it is roughly 10^5 years after 1970 or 100,000 years in the future (give or take).  That seems unlikely.  If `readDateTime` is the number of milliseconds, then it is a date 46 years after 1970 so it would be something in 2016.

Comment: So, is `readdatetime` in seconds? If so, simply write `to_date(...) + readdatetime/86400` (where the first term is for 1/1/1970); if it's in milliseconds as Justin suspects, divide by 86400000. Then you can convert to char if needed (in most cases it shouldn't be).

Comment: readdatetime is  a Unix timestamp in milliseconds since 1/1/1970. Corrected in the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex's answer is not fully correct. Unix timestamp is always based on 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**

Unless your session runs on UTC time zone the precise solution would be like this:

```
select 
   TO_CHAR((TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + readdatetime/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
from ACQDATA where ID=1000;
```

or

```
select 
   TO_CHAR((TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + readdatetime/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
from ACQDATA where ID=1000;
```

or if you prefer functions instead of literals:

```
select 
   TO_CHAR((TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') + numtodsinterval(readdatetime/1000, 'SECOND')) AT LOCAL, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
from ACQDATA where ID=1000;
```

Comment: Thanks. Better now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `readdatetime` seems to be in milliseconds. Oracle date arithmetic works on the basis of days, so you need to convert that number to the number of days it represents; one day is 86400 seconds, so it's 86400000 milliseconds:

```
with acqdata (id, readdatetime) as (
  select 1000, 1479318995000 from dual
)
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (READDATETIME/86400000), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
from ACQDATA where ID=1000;

TO_CHAR(DATE'1970-0
-------------------
2016-11-16T17:56:35
```

The `T` is added as [a character literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406).

SQL Developer defaults to show numbers that large in scientific notation. You can change that default with `set numformat`, or use `to_char()` to show the whole value:

```
select readdatetime, to_char(readdatetime, '9999999999999') as string
from ACQDATA where ID=1000;

READDATETIME STRING        
------------ --------------
  1.4793E+12  1479318995000
```

If your value has fractional seconds, so the last three digits are not zeros, you can convert the date to a timestamp and add on the fractional leftovers; this also adds the UTC 'Z' indicator for fun:

```
with acqdata (id, readdatetime) as (
  select 1000, 1479300462063 from dual
)
select to_char(cast(date '1970-01-01' + (readdatetime/86400000) as timestamp)
    + numtodsinterval(remainder(readdatetime, 1000)/1000, 'SECOND'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
from acqdata where id=1000;

TO_CHAR(CAST(DATE'1970-01-01'+
------------------------------
2016-11-16T12:47:42.063Z
```

Or without the intermediate `date` value, starting from a timestamp literal:

```
with acqdata (id, readdatetime) as (
  select 1000, 1479300462063 from dual
)
select to_char(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
  + numtodsinterval(readdatetime/1000, 'SECOND'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
from acqdata where id=1000;

TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP'1970-0
------------------------
2016-11-16T12:47:42.063Z
```

As @Wernfried ponted out, it's better to explicitly show that the epoch time is starting from UTC:

```
alter session set time_zone='America/New_York';

with acqdata (readdatetime) as (
  select 1479300462063 from dual
  union all select 1467331200000 from dual
  union all select 1467648000000 from dual
)
select readdatetime,
  to_char(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(readdatetime/1000, 'SECOND'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as implicit,
  to_char(cast(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' as timestamp with time zone)
    + numtodsinterval(readdatetime/1000, 'SECOND'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') as local_offset,
  to_char(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + numtodsinterval(readdatetime/1000, 'SECOND'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') as utc_offset,
  to_char(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + numtodsinterval(readdatetime/1000, 'SECOND'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR') as utc
from acqdata;

  READDATETIME IMPLICIT                LOCAL_OFFSET                  UTC_OFFSET                    UTC                       
-------------- ----------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------------------
 1479300462063 2016-11-16T12:47:42.063 2016-11-16T12:47:42.063-05:00 2016-11-16T12:47:42.063+00:00 2016-11-16T12:47:42.063UTC
 1467331200000 2016-07-01T00:00:00.000 2016-07-01T01:00:00.000-04:00 2016-07-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 2016-07-01T00:00:00.000UTC
 1467648000000 2016-07-04T16:00:00.000 2016-07-04T17:00:00.000-04:00 2016-07-04T16:00:00.000+00:00 2016-07-04T16:00:00.000UTC
```

Comment: Almost there. Where are the milliseconds and the `T` in the resulting string? ISO-8601 defines `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmm`. The result string contains only seconds with no T.

Comment: I've added the T. Do your values actually have millisecond values, or are the last three digits always 000?

Comment: It has specific millisecond values. Example value is `1479300462063` (063 milliseconds).

Comment: @Mendes - OK, I've updated to show how to handle that.

Comment: Yeah!! Very very helpfull Alex. Thanks.